# How do I connect to SQM database?

Tags: sql

How do I connect to SQM database? I need to make some SQL queries to this data base. The queries I want to make is of "Select * from" kind not "updates" or "inserts".

Thanking you in advance,
Sujan

Comment: Do you mean the Sky Quality Meter database?

Comment: I meant Software Quality Metrics. Sorry to have missed this.